# apache html request parameters

Tags: apache, ddos

is there any way to disable/drop queries to html contents.

```
GET /alaswaq_property.html?d691f
GET /alaswaq_property.html?48fae 
GET /alaswaq_property.html?8c106
```

GET /alaswaq_finance.html?fe082 if request contains filename.html?xxx then block it only allow filename.html < is this possible?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your htaccess file or vhost config, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[A-Za-z0-9]{5}$
RewriteRule \.html$ - [F,L]
```

If you want to simply include *any* query string at all, change the `RewriteCond` line to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
```

Comment: and if want to do for all .html files? the what will be rewrite rule syntax will be?

Comment: @Jahil I edited the answer, just realized that you wanted all html files.

Comment: how handle more then 5 character with above condition?

Comment: @Jahil You can change the regex `{5}`, if you want between 5 and 10, `{5,10}`, or one or more, `+`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use mod_rewrite to do this.

```
RewriteRule ^/alaswaq_property.html /alaswaq_property.html?
```

See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString for stuff you can do for query string manipulation.